# Max concurrent connection in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I am new in DBA role . I have a set of 20 databases where I need to do monitoring . Now what happens is, when I start with first database, it connects well , I check DB and disconnect it. Now suddenly after 3 databases check,databases stops to get connected and throws ORA-12154 TNS could not resolve the connect identifier. 
And I have to restart my system to get connected again.
I am working on windows 10. Pls suggest what can be the issue?

Comment: Are you connecting using a tnsnames.ora file?  What happens if you try to use ezconnect instead?

Comment: I am connecting using ldap

Comment: One more thing i want to add here, i just checked if DBs start to reconnect successfully without restart , if i wait for some time. Its like some variable is getting set, so DBs stop getting connected and after few mins that variable refreshes and DB start connecting.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3151285 
Similar issue is discussed and resolved.
Regrads
Subhas

Comment: Hi Subhas, ORA-12154 is not the issue in my case. when I restart my system , without making any change DB starts to connect. but as sson as I am done with 3 DBs, same problem starts to occur , even i am not able to ping the severs without restart is made.